# bash, change line in json file

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

everyone.

I have a json file:

```
{
     "id" : "123",
     "firstname" : "john",
     "lastname" : "doe",
     "tel" : "123"
}
```

fields can have any values.

Is there a way using sed, awk or anything else to change a line in this file like:

`"firstname" : "john" -> "firstname" : "bob"`

The value can be any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though json files should be handled by different editors I believe, since you have tagged `awk` here so trying to help here.

```
awk '/"firstname"/{$3="\042bob\042\054"} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
{
     "id" : "123",
"firstname" : "bob",
     "lastname" : "doe",
     "tel" : "123"
}
```

In case you want to save the output into Input_file itself then you could add `above_command > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` too.

***EDIT:*** Also if you want to keep initial space of that line, you could try following too then.

```
awk '/"firstname"/{$1="     "$1;$3="\042bob\042\054"} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows then.

```
{
     "id" : "123",
     "firstname" : "bob",
     "lastname" : "doe",
     "tel" : "123"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update value in json file with jq:

```
jq '."firstname" = "bob"' file
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "firstname": "bob",
  "lastname": "doe",
  "tel": "123"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another in awk. Using `sub()` and regex to replace the last quoted string on a record with string `filename` on it:

```
$ awk '/firstname/{sub(/\"[^\"]*\",?$/,"\"bob\"")}1' file
{
     "id" : "123",
     "firstname" : "bob"
     "lastname" : "doe",
     "tel" : "123"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in nawk and mawk as well.

```
    awk '{sub(/john/,"bob")}1' file

output
{
     "id" : "123",
     "firstname" : "bob",
     "lastname" : "doe",
     "tel" : "123"
}
```